# How to adjust button css styles

Tags: css, styling

I currently have css styles for buttons that look a bit outdated.  Here is my css:

```
a.yellow_button {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.2em;
-moz-border-radius: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
-webkit-border-radius: 14px;
border-radius: 14px;

background: #ffce2e;
color: #444;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.9);

-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

border: 1px solid #444;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px 6px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right: 2px;

float:none; 
display: inline-block;

}

a.yellow_button:hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ff0;
color: #000;
}
```

You can see these buttons as they currently appear on comehike.com making the site's design kind of old looking.

What I need to do is make the buttons look like the yellow button on the top-right of this mockup:

[image]

Any idea which part of the css I should change to get that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. This will do it.

```
.whatever-the-class-is {
  /* No border */
  border-style:none;
```

Now for some shadow

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

And the curved border

```
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
```

Finally, the gradient. This code is designed to work in alot of browsers.

```
  background: #bfc126; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bfc126 0%, #ffff00 100%); /* Firefox */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bfc126 0%,#ffff00 100%); /* Chrome, Safari */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bfc126 0%,#ffff00 100%); /* Opera */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bfc126 0%,#ffff00 100%); /* IE */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #bfc126 0%,#ffff00 100%); /* Probably should include this aswell */
}
```

You could create an image of the gradient, but this would take time, and would make the page slower to load.

Comment: I almost got it, but for some reason here the buttons are not yellow but some sort of green: http://www.comehike.com/hikes/park.php?park_id=5 any idea why? :)

Comment: Do you mean the top of the gradient? I made that on purpose, becuase it was like that in the picture you gave. I can change it, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

http://www.zurb.com/article/266/super-awesome-buttons-with-css3-and-rgba

or this:

http://css3buttongenerator.com/

Both sites give similar buttons, the first link is probably more relevant, you will just need to make them a bit taller.

Answer (score 1):

To create the yellow gradient, you can either use a background image, or you can make use of CSS-gradients, like in [this example](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient). You will of course have to change to colors, but something like this:

```
background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
```

To get the rounded corners you use the CSS `border-radius` property, [reference](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/). It would be something like:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

To get the white 1px text-shadow you can use the CSS `text-shadow` property, [reference](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/). Something like:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
```

**Notice** that there will be limited browser support on this solution, as it is CSS3. Older browsers will ignore the rounded corners and the text-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.yellow_button {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  background: #dac303; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dac303 0%, #f1e000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dac303), color-stop(100%,#f1e000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dac303 0%,#f1e000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #dac303 0%,#f1e000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #dac303 0%,#f1e000 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #dac303 0%,#f1e000 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dac303', endColorstr='#f1e000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

That should get you started with the button and the `text-shadow` for the text. Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: that didn't work. It made the buttons look pretty broken..hard to describe exactly how.